# No image or text appears when attemping to share to Twitter/Instagram using Xamarin.Essentials

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.essentials

I am using Xamarin.Essentials share feature but with lackluster success.

If i do a:

```
await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareTextRequest
{
     Text = "Works",
     Title = "Not working"                   
});
```

and open Twitter or Instagram or Whatsapp, i cannot see the Title, only the text getting filled.

If i do:

```
await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareFileRequest
{
     Title = title,
     File = new ShareFile(post.Image, "image/jpeg")
});
```

Then i cannot see either text or an image when attempting to share it to twitter or instagram. Is this a known bug or is it simply because these platforms doesn't support it?

"post.Image" has a valid .jpeg https url to it.

Comment: I found the document states that [Title not used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/share?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=ios#platform-differences) in iOS. That maybe the cause.

Comment: hmm ok, but i still see no image?

Comment: Can you try another png/jpg image? Are you using the latest version of Xamarin.Essentials?

Comment: Latest version yes. i can try 1 sec

Comment: nop still issues. also, the "Title" or anyhting text related never shows on iOS, making this plugin pretty (?) useless if u ask me.

Comment: You can open an issue in Github for those problems. You can also check the source code [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/blob/main/Xamarin.Essentials/Share/Share.ios.cs).